# Server for traffic redirection with static IP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, server, ip, traffic

I use app engine on google cloud for my webserver. The webserver must communicate with APIs to fetch all kind of data from clients.

For a specific client, I need a static IP for my server for it to be whitelisted. However, I can't control this on app engine. I thought about creating somewhere a server acting as a traffic rerouting with a static IP address. What would be the best solutions for this ?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I'd suggest to do a better investigation next time https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip

Comment: actually I tried this, but never managed to make it work. Moreover, I don't want to apply this for all my server, behaviour for other APIs is fine as is.
Any help appreciated on this.

Comment: Then you need to create a proxy so instead of calling the external service you call the proxy and it calls the service. For example use a GCE VM. Anyway the question is about infrastructure design rather than coding issues with is off-topic

Comment: Yes, I just understood by reading the doc again. Was completely lost before. Now what I do not get is how to configure the cloud NAT to be able to call an API from my server through my static outbound IP. Will do another post. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up a static IP address for your App Engine standard environment service, use **[Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access)** with Cloud Router and **[Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs)**. By using Serverless VPC Access, you can send egress traffic to your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network. By using a network address translation (NAT) gateway on your VPC, you can route the App Engine traffic through a dedicated IP address.

Routing your traffic through Cloud NAT does not cause an additional hop in your networking stack since the Cloud NAT gateway and the Cloud Router provide only a control plane and the packets do not pass through the Cloud NAT gateway or the Cloud Router.

In order to send traffic with external destinations to your VPC network so that it will have the static IP address that you specified, you must change the egress setting to **`all-traffic`**.

And as mentioned by **@Ferregina Pelona** if you don’t want to apply this for all servers, then you will need to create a proxy so instead of calling the external service you can call the proxy and it calls the service.

Follow the steps mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip) to set up a static outbound IP address.